# Facebook share/Like not loading thumbnail image

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The thumbnail of the site is not loading in Facebook when being shared/liked. I have the following within the head section of my HTML:

```
<meta property="og:image" 
           content="http://img.loveculture.com/ProductThumbs/1039103_29_1.jpg" />
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" 
              href="http://img.loveculture.com/ProductThumbs/1039103_29_1.jpg" />
```

According to [Facebook's test page](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.loveculture.com%2FItem%2FItemDetailView.aspx%3FStyleId%3D1038065) it passes with flying colors:

- The images are in fact there.
- The images are small and in JPEG format.
- I waited 24 hours (possible Facebook cache issue)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue for a couple of weeks and my only solution was to put the image on a different domain.

It is a bug with Facebook but not enough people seem to be having the issue to justify them spending time on trying to fix it.

I do hope they fix it soon though, it's a pain to try to explain to my boss that a single image has to be hosted somewhere random because of a Facebook bug.

Comment: Thank you.  Yeah, it's such a nightmare.  I went ahead and sent a request to Facebook to join their support Blog and possibly post this issue there.  In the end, I feel it might be an internal FB bug or possibly a FB cache issue.  We shall see.

Comment: Please send me a link to the bug report when you add it, I'll verify that I could reproduce the bug and hopefully we can get it fixed soon.

Comment: The report is at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.loveculture.com%2FItem%2FItemDetailView.aspx%3FStyleId%3D1038065

Comment: The page is at http://dev.loveculture.com/Item/ItemDetailView.aspx?StyleId=1038065

Comment: You should create a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs  the Facebook staff is pretty good about fixing issues immediately  when several people confirm that they can reproduce the issue.

Comment: The Facebook bug page has a nasty bug...  Can't create a post.  Oh well.  I'm glad I have this website to vent/post.